# Encountering 404 Error when deploying site via GitHub Pages

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, github, web

I am trying to deploy my website using GitHub Pages, but I'm facing an issue with a 404 error. Here's the link to my repository: https://github.com/brissal/test.

I've followed the GitHub Pages instructions, but it seems that something is going wrong. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What I Tried:
I followed the GitHub Pages documentation to deploy my website. Specifically, I pushed my HTML, CSS, and other relevant files to the "gh-pages" branch of my repository (link: https://github.com/brissal/test). I waited for the GitHub Pages build to complete.

Expectations:
I expected my site to be accessible at the specified GitHub Pages URL (usually in the format: https://username.github.io/repository). However, I encountered a 404 error instead.

Additional Information:

The "gh-pages" branch is correctly configured as the source for GitHub Pages in the repository settings.
I've ensured that my main HTML file (e.g., index.html) is in the root directory of the "gh-pages" branch.
I appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this 404 error. Thank you!

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your "Actions" that have the CI/CD for deployment: https://github.com/brissal/test/actions/runs/7320472190/job/19939628456 If I click through to https://pipelinesghubeus9.actions.githubusercontent.com/FmuAGnbCeNKRJCYesURkm3xLdubPmoEVlcHz7jEBM5tZLuHJX6/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/3/artifacts?artifactName=github-pages&%24expand=SignedContent I see the error:

> #### UnauthorizedRequestException
>
> The user 'System:PublicAccess;aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.

It looks like Github pages is not set up properly, there is a temporary error, or Github pages has a bug.